# @Section Scripts in ASP.Net (VB)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, razor

This is driving me nuts. I am a C# coder currently having to alter a VB.Net web app. I have

In _Layout.vbhtml

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)
```

In the view,  when I add

```
 @Section Scripts
        <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo-grid-utilities/kendo-grid-filter-menu-sorter.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
 End Section
```

the page just 404s - any clues?

Comment: _"the page just 404s"_ ... Is it the script that 404 or the `_Layout.vbhtml' page the script is being rendered on?

Comment: Also, not sure if it will matter but `@Section Scripts` (uppercase 'S') and `@RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)` (lowercase 's')

Comment: The actual page (as far as I can tell, its rendered in a Kendo Window and that is blank, the main part of the app is fine). And upper/lowercase was a reasonable guess, but makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Have you maybe tried the following?

```
@Section Scripts
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo-grid-utilities/kendo-grid-filter-menu-sorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
End Section
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you should translate de section name exactly as in Layout

> `@RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)`

```
 @Section scripts

    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo-gridutilities/kendogridfiltermenu-sorter.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>

End Section
```